# Depreciation warning for colors in Angular

Tags: angular, sass

I am using SASS in my Angular Application.
Below is my colors.scss

```
$app-color-eggplant: #232028;
$app-color-dust: #ABAAAF;
$app-color-off: #9B8BC6;
$app-color-shadow: #1A0438;

    //Primary Colors
    $color-primary                  : #472A93;
    $color-primary-darkest          : #212028;
    $color-primary-light            : #A596CC;


    //Secondary Colors
    $color-secondary                : #FF6601;
    $color-secondary-light          : #FFC19A;


    //Informational Colors
    $color-error                    : #DB4432;


    //Text Colors
    $color-text                     : #232028;
    $color-text-muted               : #797979;
    $color-text-light               : #D2D2D2;


    //Background Colors
    $color-background               : #cfd8dc;
    $color-background-dark          : #b0bec5;
    $color-background-darker        : #90A4AE;
    $color-background-light         : #EDEFF1;
    $color-background-table         : #c6c6c6;
    $color-background-table-lighter : #c6c6c636;
```

My application is up and running but it gives me this warning while compilation

> The value "#c6c6c636" is currently parsed as a string, but it will be
>   parsed as a color in future versions of Sass. Use
>   "unquote('#c6c6c636')" to continue parsing it as a string.

The solution Provided in **[here](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/2478)** ain't working or probably I am doing something wrong

```
$app-color-dust: rgba(#ABAAAF);
$app-color-off: rgba(#9B8BC6);
```

It gives me below Error

> Module build failed: $app-color-dust: rgba(#ABAAAF) ;
>                   ^
>         Overloaded function `rgba` given wrong number of arguments
>         in C:\myapp\services\src\app\styles\app-colors.scss (line 2, column 18)

How to fix this or should I continue without worrying about the warnings?

Comment: My guess is it is now parsed as a string (`#c6c6c636`), and it will later be parsed as a color (`rgba(198, 198, 198, 0.54)`). Since that's aonly a warning, you can ignore that as long as it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try passing in an opacity value, or use `rgb` instead of `rgba`. Just make sure you pass some `alpha` value when using `rgba`.

```
rgb(#ABAAAF)
rgba(#c6c6c6, 0.36)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no color with hex like `#c6c6c636`. Check your hex is it correct? If you want lighter version use `rgba(198, 198, 198, 0.36)`